# Freeform AJAX not returning JSON

Tags: solspace-freeform, ajax

I'm using a freeform with ajax but the response comes back as index.php?ACT=11 and not JSON and therefore I can't manipulate the response. How can I have freeform return JSON instead?

Freeform looks like this:

```
{exp:freeform:form
form_name="contact_me"
required="first_name|last_name|email|user_message"
recipients="no"
inline_errors="yes"
admin_notify="you@me.com"
notify_admin="yes"
admin_notification_template="contact_form"
form:id="contact-form"
}
```

My ajaxForm code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#contact-form').ajaxForm({ 
    target: '#form-response',
    success: function() {
                    //$('.formText').hide();
        $('#form-response').fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, JSON data doesn't return when you have inline_errors="yes", try to remove inline_error attribute from your form.